# How to I execute python code in parallel using Azure Container Apps as the backend (or other serverless infra)?

Tags: python-multiprocessing, azure-container-instances, azure-container-apps, parallel-python

I have some embarasingly parallel code that I'd like to scale against a "serverless" backend like Azure Container Apps (or instances, or any other "containers on demand" service).

I am writing my own implementation, but I feel I'm re-inventing the wheel here.

Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate what I'm trying to build:

```py
# Before
def compute_stuff(input_value:float)->float:
    ...


result = []
for i in range(1000):
   result.append(
      compute_stuff(i)
     )

# After

results = run_in_container_apps(  # Maybe some async stuff as well
                  func=compute_stuff, 
                  parameters=[i for i in range(1000)], 
                  n_instances=-1
              )
```

I looked into AzureML / Kubernetes, but I feel that what I'm looking for is a little simpler.